# Proper use of create_autospec

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am reading through [this example](https://gist.github.com/slinkp/c3ec1f47d7ecfe682ad4) of a mock created by create_autospec.

In the example, the author creates a class called Foo, with method `bar`, which returns `pass`

He then proceeds to demonstrate create_autospec

```
BetterMockFoo = mock.create_autospec(Foo)
foo = BetterMockFoo()
foo.bar()
```

this returns the following

> `<MagicMock name='mock().bar()' id='17171792'>`

I don't understand why you would want to do this. What value is created by this method?

Answer (score 0):

The three lines you have included just demonstrate the happy path -- if one calls the mock object's `bar` method it doesn't fail, as expected. The return value doesn't matter.

If you were to call `foo.baz()`, it would blow up because the mocked class `Foo` doesn't have that method.